# making text appear when the user sends input into a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get it so when the input isn't empty it will display what is in the input.

```
<div>
    <input name="helpme" type="text" id="helpme" size="16" maxlength="32" value="">
</div>
<cfif helpme neq ""> 
    <style>document.getElementById("a").style.display="block";</style> 
</cfif>
<pre>
    <font size=+1>
        <div style="display:none" id=a>hello: 
            <font color=red>#trim(helpme)#</font>
        </div>
    </font>
</pre>
```

When you put an input in nothing happens.

Comment: Please provide a runnable snippet and indent your code.

Comment: Plus: `<style>document.getElementById("a").style.display="block";</style>` you set JS in a style tag. Quite strange.

Comment: Not sure I follow. What do you mean by "put an input in"? Do something when a user types characters into the `<input>` field, when the form loads - display the value of #helpme# in the `<input>` field, or something else?

Comment: If you want this done on the client side, you have to use a client side technology. ColdFusion is a server side technology. It responds to things like form submits and href clicks. (Certain exceptions may apply)

Answer (score 3):

I found that a few `""` were missing around id names and updated the code a little but this works. Here there is a method triggered onkeyup so the value is looked for each time you type a character

```js
function showValue() {
  var input = document.getElementById('helpme').value;
  document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = input;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="helpme" type="text" id="helpme" size="16" maxlength="32" value="" onkeyup="showValue()"/>
</div>

<pre>
  <font size=+1>
    <p>hello: <font color="red" id="a"></font>
    </p>
  </font>
</pre>
```